# Problems Converting Postgres field to variable nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a working function.

```
function getSingleRecord(req, res, next) {
 var appID = req.params.id;
db.any('select name from "Metadatastore".resource where 
def = \'ABCVBGT\'')
.then(function (data) {
  res.status(200)
    .json({
      status: 'success',
      data: data,
      message: 'Retrieved ONE record'
       });
     })
```

I need to convert the bold field value abcvbgt to a variable.  The variable is appID.  I have tried several methods and it did not work.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by "convert .. to a variable" ?

Comment: I need to replace the db query field value of ABCDVBGT with the value of var appID.  I want the field value of the db query to be replaced with the var appID.  Make sense?

Comment: Just a note - recommend taking a look at knex.js which is a querybuilder that can help simplifiy a lot of interactions with PG / MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use placeholders. In this case `$1` will be replaced by the value of `appID`. Your question does not mention which postgres module you are using, but this should be supported by pretty much all good modules.

```
function getSingleRecord(req, res, next) {
 var appID = req.params.id;
db.any('select name from "Metadatastore".resource where def = $1', appID)
.then(function (data) {
  res.status(200)
    .json({
      status: 'success',
      data: data,
      message: 'Retrieved ONE record'
       });
     })
```